# Invalid operands to Binary expression ('id' and 'int')

Tags: objective-c, expression, operands

I've this objective C code and I'm trying to apply tint effect to an image at pixel level. When I shift by 16 bits and 8 bits and then mask accordingly to get separate channels, I'm getting this error. Can someone help me out?

```
-(void) Tint :(NSArray *)pixels :(int) intensity
{

    intensity+=20;
    int RY, BY, RYY, GYY, BYY, R, G, B, Y;
    double angle = (3.14 * (double)intensity) / 180;
    int index=0;
    int S = (int)(256 * sin(angle));
    int C = (int)(256 * cos(angle));
    int r,g,b;
    for (int y = 0; y < [p1 height]; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < [p1 width]; x++)
        {
            r = ( [pixels objectAtIndex :x] >> 16 ) & 0xff;
            g = ( [pixels objectAtIndex :x] >> 8 ) & 0xff;
            b = [pixels objectAtIndex :x] & 0xff;
            index++;
        }
}
```

Comment: `objectAtIndex` returns `id`. What does the pixels array contain?

Comment: Would be interesting to name methods "normally" and respect some nomenclature: `-(void)tintPixels:(NSArray*)pixels withIntensity:(int)intensity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption: NSArray is filled with NSNumber;

```
NSNumber* rgNumber = [pixels objectAtIndex:x];

r = ([rgNumber intValue] >> 16) & 0xff;
g = ([rgNumber intValue] >> 8) & 0xff;
```

Answer (score 0):

`objectAtIndex:` returns an *object* of the type `id`.

I suspect the objects stored in pixels are NSNumbers. If so, then this is what you meant to do.

```
int pixel = [pixels[x] intValue];
r = ( pixel >> 16 ) & 0xff;
```